# How to automatically set a large number of external variables to a given value?

Tags: javascript

I have an interesting problem which has me stumped quite a bit. Many thanks in advance for any assistance.

The basic situation is as follows. I'm writing a general script file, `general.js`, for use with a large number of web pages, each of which has its own associated script file `pageN.js`. Each of these `pageN` files contains a large number of variables `t1`,...,`tn`, with *n* different for each page. (Usually *n* will be between 50 and 100.)

In `general.js` I have a "lightswitch" function:

```
function onOff(t,binaryDigit){
   if ( binaryDigit == 0 ) { // hide graphic element associated with t
   }
   else { // show graphic element associated with t
   }
}
```

and also a function that applies `onOff` to an arbitrary number of  ordered pairs `[tk,binaryDigit]`:

```
function myFunction() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        onOff(arguments[i][0],arguments[i][1])
    }
}
```

Since I'm going to call `myFunction` often, and each time most binaryDigits will have to be set to 0, I would like to build a `helperFunction` in which I only need to specify the `tk` for which I want `binaryDigit` to be 1 and which sets the other binary digits to 0. So, for example, if *n* = 50, then calling `helperFunction(t1,t2,t3)` should execute `myFunction([t1,1],[t2,1],[t3,1],[t4,0],...,[t50,0])`.

My question is: how should I do this? I have only limited experience with advanced JavaScript, so I haven't got a clue, to be honest.`

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by myself, after giving it some further thought (on the toilet). My solution is to generate for each `pageN.js` file an array, called `variableArray`, that is essentially a list of all the variables in that file. Next, I define my `helperFunction` in `general.js` as follows:

```
var helperFunction = function() {
    var argArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var varArray = argArray[argArray.length-1];
    var elementsOff = $(varArray).not($(argArray)).get();
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        onOff(arguments[i],1);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < elementsOff.length; i++) {
    onOff(elementsOff[i],0);
   }
};
```

The functions gets called like this: `helperFunction(t1,t2,t3,variableArray)`.